# f:R2->R2 where f(x,y)=(x+y,y)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$, where $f(x,y)=(x+y,x)$, one-to-one, onto, both?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286164/is-the-function-f-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr2-where-fx-y-xy-x-one-to)

Determine whether the function is one-to-one, onto, and if both than describe its inverse. Can you fully explain to. Thanks. I'm not really familiar with mapping and I can't figure out how to make it into a linear algebra problem.

Comment: Why did you ask this question again? I will merge this duplicate copy with the original