# Prove that $f(m,n)=(m+2n, m-n)$ is 1-1 and Onto. The domain and co-domain are $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I know how to prove injectivity $f(x)=f(y)\Rightarrow x=y$ and surjectivity but am not sure how to go about it in this case since there are multi variables.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286164/is-the-function-f-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr2-where-fx-y-xy-x-one-to).

Answer (score 4):

Note that $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$ is given by $f(x)=Ax$ where 
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
But $\det A=-1-2=-3\neq0$ so $A$ is invertible. Hence $f$ is one-to-one and onto.

Answer (score 1):

The methods are precisely the same.  For injectivity, you assume

$f(m_1,n_1) = f(m_2, n_2)$ and show that this implies $(m_1,n_1) = (m_2,n_2)$. For surjectivity, you take a generic point, say $(x,y)$, and you need to find the choice of $(m,n)$ such that $f(m,n) = (x,y)$.

Comment: @RoyM: And the equations, since they involve ordered pairs, become systems of equations (one equation for each coordinate)